# Как объединить таблицы из Excel?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Есть N таблиц в Excel с разными данными, но в каждой есть одинаковое поле.

table1

| Имя сервера | Стенд | Используется (Да/Нет) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dev1 | Тест | Да |
| prom2 | Пром | Да |
| data2 | Тест | Нет |
| data24 | Пром | Да |

table2

| ip | Имя сервера | CPU |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.10.2 | data2 | 24 |
| 10.1.24 | data24 | 12 |
| 10.1.2 | prom2 | 4 |
| 10.10.1 | dev1 | 8 |

Нужно объединить таблицы по полю `Имя сервера`. Причем, строчки в этих полях идут вразнобой.

Я смотрел библиотеку Pandas, но не могу понять, как сделать не построчное объеденение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно считать файлы excel в датафреймы:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_xlsx("первый файл.xls")
df2 = pd.read_xlsx("второй файл.xls")
```

Затем просто сделать merge:

```
res = df1.merge(df2, on="Имя сервера", how="outer")
```

на вашем примере, res будет

```
  Имя сервера Стенд Используется (Да/Нет)           ip  CPU
0        dev1  Тест                    Да      10.10.1    8
1       prom2  Пром                    Да       10.1.2    4
2       data2  Тест                   Нет      10.10.2   24
3      data24  Пром                    Да      10.1.24   12
```

Comment: Спасибо! У меня получилось, но только после установки еще двух библиотек: openpyxl и xlrd

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь методом [pandas.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), чтобы объединить сразу все фреймы:

```
res = pd.concat(
    [pd.read_excel(f).set_index("Имя сервера") for f in list_of_excel_files],
    axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: Мне так же подошел этот вариант, спасибо большое за помощь в решении вопроса!